# Sbt's gen-idea always creates two IntelliJ projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to SBT. Just be curious that why does sbt's gen-idea always generate two IntelliJ projects:

```
 .idea
 .idea_modules
```

When I open the generated project, the "project" directory is always there as a separate project different with the top level project. The name is "myproject-build".

Just wondering whether this is normal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal, this is the default behavior. You can change it by excluding some folders (see the doc available here : https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea at **Exclude some folders**)

**So what is the difference between .idea and .idea_modules?**

.idea_module generates an IDEA module while .idea generates an IDEA project.

*In short* a project can be multi-module or single-module and also contains IntelliJ libraries.

*In longer version* from the doc (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Structure+of+IntelliJ+IDEA+Project)

**Project**

> In IntelliJ IDEA, a project encapsulates all your source code,
>   libraries, build instructions into a single organizational unit.
>   Everything you do in IntelliJ IDEA, is done within the context of a
>   project. A project defines some collections referred to as modules and
>   libraries. Depending on the logical and functional requirements to the
>   project, you can create a single-module or a multi-module project.

**Module**

> A module is a discrete unit of functionality that can be run, tested,
>   and debugged independently. Modules includes such things as source
>   code, build scripts, unit tests, deployment descriptors, etc. In the
>   project, each module can use a specific SDK or inherit SDK defined on
>   the project level (see the SDK section later in this document). A
>   module can depend on other modules of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ok for that SBT plugin for IDEA.

Usually IDEA project consists of top-level `.idea` directory (which contains configuration common to the project) and several `*.iml` files, one for each module in the project (module-specific configuration, like facets, excluded directories, custom dependencies). These files are usually located in the top-level directories of corresponding modules.

On the other hand, SBT plugin does something unusual. It creates standard `.idea` directory, but it stores all project modules in one location, namely `.idea_modules` directory in the top-level directory of the project. This is fully supported by IDEA project structure, which is a set of XMLs after all.

As for `project` directory/module, it is a standard feature of SBT builds. It contains your build configuration. See [SBT manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Directories.html#sbt-build-definition-files) on this.

The foregoing was about SBT plugin which is currently present in plugins repo. There is an [official SBT plugin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/) in active development which keeps familiar modules structure (no `.idea_modules` directory) and has higher integration with SBT. The latter is most prominent in dependency management - official plugin extracts dependencies, even unmanaged, and makes them available for the IDE; current SBT plugin cannot do that.